# Trouble iterating Generic list with custom object

Tags: c#

Here's the code:

```
    ProductList products = xxx.GetCarProducts(productCount);
    List<CarImageList> imageList = new List<CarImageList>();


    foreach(Product p in products)
    {
        string imageTag = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(string.Format(@"<img src=""{0}"" alt="""">", ImageUrl(p.Image, false)));

        imageList.Add(new CarImageList{ImageTag = imageTag});
        i++;
    }
```

Under the covers ProductList is really defined like this:

```
public class ProductList : List<Product>
{
    static Random rand = new Random();

    public ProductList Shuffle()
    {
        ProductList list = new ProductList();
        list.AddRange(this);

        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            int r = rand.Next(list.Count - 1);
            Product swap = list[i];
            list[i] = list[r];
            list[r] = swap;
        }

        return list;
    }

    public Product FindById(int id)
    {
        foreach (Product p in this)
            if (p.Id == id) return p;

        return null;
    }

    public Product GetRandom()
    {
        int r = rand.Next(this.Count - 1);
        return this[r];
    }
}
```

so why do I get the error when I try to foreach through the ProductList instance?

Cannot convert type 'xxx.Product' to 'Product' is the error I get.  But if ProductList is really List why in the world would it have an issue with conversion?

Comment: What does GetCarProducts look like?  Are you using LinqToSQL?  If so, the error may be in GetCarProducts but it's not showing up until you try to iterate over the collection.

Comment: GetCarProducts returns type ProductList.  No not using LINQ

Comment: tried this but no luck, says it can't convert ProductList products = GetCarProducts(productCount); List<Product> prods = products;

Comment: You can press Ctrl+C in the Error List to copy an error message.  Can you please paste the exact text of the error?

Comment: runtime: Cannot convert type 'xxnamespace.ProductList' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Product>'

Comment: I know when I moused over Product I saw that it was the right namespace.  But for some reason I still had to preface it with the namespace and walla, it's resolved.  Weird.

Comment: Sounds like a namespace conflict to me... If there's two different classes of the same name in your imported namespaces, it requires you to disambiguate them.

Comment: But that's the thing, there is NOT 2 different Product.cs in any of our assemblies.

Comment: ProductList.cs and Product.cs are in the same namespace but I don't think that should matter?  I mean the fact that ProductList : List<Product> and that both these classes are in the same namespace to me should not pose an issue whatsoever.  I Understand if we had two completely different Product.cs and you'd need to specify the namespace in that case but that's not the case here.

Comment: You don't need a file Product.cs to have a second Product class though. Anyway, good to hear you got it sorted out.

Comment: true, I'll hunt again.  thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that `Product` in the context of the first example is a different `Product` type than `Product` in the context of the second example.  Are you sure you have your namespaces sorted out?

Comment: they are of the same namespace

Answer (score 1):

I think your `xxx.GetCarProducts(productCount);` may be returning a reference to `List<Product>` which is less defined than your `ProductList` class, meaning in your GetCarProducts method you probably do new `List<Product>` instead of `new ProductList()`.

If anything can you post the body of `GetCarProducts`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have two different classes, both called "Product", but in different namespaces/classes. (Public) nested classes are a bad idea, because they can exacerbate this sort of issue... I'd check that both your references to `Product` are actually the same class.

**EDIT:**

```
void Main()
{
    ProductList products = new ProductList();
    products.Add(new Product("foo"));
    products.Add(new Product("bar"));

    foreach(Product p in products)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
    }
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class ProductList : List<Product>
{ /* [snip] the other stuff is irrelevant */ }

public class Product 
{
    public Product(string name)
    { Name = name; }
    public string Name;
}
```

Comment: both references to product definitely are to the same class

Comment: The above code works perfectly for me... are you SURE there is no namespace clashes?

Comment: what do you presume to do other than public nested classes?

Comment: I am absolutely sure there is one and only one definition that has "public class Product" anywhere in all of the assemblies being used in my web project.

Comment: What I don't  understand is that to solve this I had to preface the "Product" with the namespace even though I included that namespace with a using statement and even though I am 100% sure that there is only one definition for class Product and it definitely is in that namespace.

Comment: I'm not calling you a liar, but from what you've posted so far, it would seem that the compiler is having issues with your assertions.

Comment: Unnest it if it needs to be public, or create an abstract class/interface that it can inherit from, have that unnested and make the nested class private/protected.

Answer (score 0):

You might have two different `Product` types in different namespaces, or you might be missing a `using` statement.

As an aside, custom collection classes (such as `ProductList`) should inherit from [`System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397.aspx).

Comment: they are of the same namespace so no issue there.

Comment: What is the exact error message?  Is it at runtime or compile time?

Comment: runtime:

Cannot convert type 'xxnamespace.ProductList' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Product>'

Comment: I moused over Product in the ProductList class definition after the : List<Product> and it is indeed the same namespace as the namespace ProductList is in and the same namespace in the Product.cs